# JQuery UI droppable accept and drop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the JQuery UI draggable and droppable. But it looks like `ui.droppable` is **undefined**. Can someone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance : "pointer",
    accept : ".acceptable",
    drop : function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.hide(500, function() {
            var position = ui.droppable.attr("id");
            built(position.replace("position", ""), 
            ui.draggable.attr("id"));
            ui.draggable.remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Thank you for your efford, i just found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution somehow i missed it, i also was trying `$(this).droppable.attr("id");` wich was undefined aswell somehow i missed that i use $(this) inside of the hide, callback function where $(this) is the draggable object it worked by moving the line code out of the hide function.